# Почему искажается текст

Tags: javascript, php, html5

мне нужно создать программу которая берёт html с дива и скачивает как html-файл. Но у меня проблема: после скачивания и открытия файла текст на русском языке искажается, а на английском нет почему?
**PHP:**

```
if (isset ($_POST["s"])) {
        $install_context = file_get_contents("install.html");
         require_once("write_me.html");
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="inst">
  <?php echo $install_context; ?>
</div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
document.querySelector("#sss").onclick = () => {
    alert("Привет, етот чат только експериментальный, через несколько дней чат будет обнуляться, если вы хотите возобновить сообщения, то напишите в етот чат мне и я предоставлю ссылку по которой вы сможете либо скачать сообщения, либо открыть их в новой вкладке.");
    let install_content = document.querySelector("#inst").innerHTML;
    let link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = "hello.html";
    let blob = new Blob([install_content], {type: "text/html"});
    let f = new FileReader();
    f.readAsDataURL(blob);
    f.onloadend = () => {
        link.href = f.result;
        link.click();
        
    }
}
```

Вот ссылка на пример:

[Мой пример](https://math-1.vova2020.repl.co)

Инструкция:

1. Перейдите в чат:

[image: чат]

2. Нажмите на кнопку:
   [image: нажмите]
3. И теперь сюда:
   [image: нажмите]

Етот пример скачает файл с сообщениями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего это потому, что в html файле прописаны локальные ссылки на css и js файлы. У вас их нет, вот страничка и ломается

Comment: Ясно, спасибо вам большое